# Неверный sql запрос, как я понимаю

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Заношу новые данные пользователей в БД по их запросу.

```php
$new_user_login = trim($_POST['new_user_login']);

$qSQL = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE users SET user_login ='".$new_user_login."' WHERE user_login='".$current_user_data['user_login']."' ");
```

Не заменяет данные.

Попробовал такой запрос через mysql просто ввести:
`UPDATE users SET user_login = "Tiptest" WHERE user_login = "Tipo_4ek"`
Все работает и заменяет. В чем проблема возникает в php, вроде запрос правильно составил

Comment: Выведите текст запроса и посмотрите на него.

Comment: В чем угодно, например в $current_user_data['user_login'] несуществующий логин. Проверяйте результат выполнения update, печатайте ошибки, при их возникновении. Так же может быть полезным проверка количества обработанных строк (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.affected-rows.php). Кроме того стоит использовать подготовленные выражения и привязку аргументов (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) потому как в текущем варианте внеся кавычки в форму в new_user_login можно модифицировать в таблице что угодно, например пароль и не только текущего пользователя

Comment: @Mike А как можно изменить "внеся кавычки в форму в new_user_login"? Не совсем понимаю

Comment: посмотрите примеры кода в приведенной ссылке, там показано, что в запросе пишут `?`, а потом привязывают к ним значения. Сейчас если new_user_login равен скажем `xxx", password=123, rights="admin` атакующий поменяет значения полей с паролем и правами (например) или что там еще в users есть

Comment: Откуда берется `$current_user_data['user_login']` ? Возможно, эти данные тоже нужно обновлять после первой смены логина.

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_user_login = trim($_POST['new_user_login']);

$qSQL = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE users SET user_login ='".$new_user_login."' WHERE user_login='".$current_user_data['user_login']."' ");
```

---

Так:
    $newULogin = trim ($_POST['new_user_login']);

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET user_login = {$newULogin} WHERE user_login = {$currentUData['user_login']}";
$query = mysqli_query ($connection, $sql);
```

---

В данном месте sql обрывается, можно было на изи задампить (

> =' ".$current_user_data[ '

).